# Show that $\{1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \alpha^3\}$ is an integral basis in $k$, ( i.e. show that $\mathcal{O}_k = \Bbb{Z}[\alpha]$.)

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $k = \Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is a root of the polynomial $m(X) = X^4 − 3.$

I have already shown $m$ is irreducible and worked out the the discriminant of $\{1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \alpha^3\}$. The discriminant is $-6912$ which has 2 square divisors $2$ and $3$.

Show that $\{1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \alpha^3\}$ is an integral basis in $k$, ( i.e. show that $\mathcal{O}_k = \Bbb{Z}[\alpha]$.)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: These questions always seem to involve a lot of heavy lifting. First, what form a priori can elements of the ring of integers, but not in your integral basis take? Computing norms and minimal polynomials, and seeing these are not integral, should take care of it

Comment: I took the liberty of TeXifying your post. We commonly typeset math formulas using MathJax (a LaTeX-interpreter well suited for posting math in WWW). Do take a look at [the tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/11619). You can just click the "edit" button under your post to see what I did to your post.

Comment: If $z=a+b\alpha+c\alpha^2+d\alpha^3$ is integral over $\Bbb{Q}$, then it must also be integral over the intermediate field $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha^2)=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt3)$, and we know the ring of integers of that intermediate field to be $R=\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt3]$. The trace of $z$ to that intermediate field is $2a+2c\alpha^2$. For this to be in $R$ we need $2a,2c\in\Bbb{Z}$. You can do the same to $\alpha z$, leaving a finite search space to cover.

Comment: It looks like some voter thinks your question has too little context. You may want to check out [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619) to see what is expected from questions. If you can make any progress, it is a good idea to edit that in.

Comment: For what it's worth, the LMFDB says the integral basis is $1, a, a^2, a^3$, but I don't quite see where it says that their $a$ corresponds to your $\alpha$, which I'm guessing is $\root 4 \of 3$. http://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/4.2.6912.1 From that I went to Wolfram Alpha and put in `NumberFieldFundamentalUnits[3^(1/4)]`, but there is the caveat that this can be misleading (e.g., the fundamental unit of $\mathcal O_{\mathbb Q(\sqrt{17})}$ is $4 + \sqrt{17}$.

Comment: @RobertSoupe, LMFDB: "A generator of a number field K, is an element a∈K such that $K=\mathbb Q(a)$. A root of its defining polynomial is a generator of K."

Comment: Hence, LMFDB says that $1, \sqrt[4]{3}, \sqrt[4]{3}^2, \sqrt[4]{3}^3$ is an integral basis of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{3})\subseteq \mathbb R$. Also that $1,i\sqrt[4]{3},-\sqrt[4]{3}^2, -i\sqrt[4]{3}^3$ is an integral basis of the field $\mathbb Q[i\sqrt[4]{3}]\subset \mathbb C$.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend the lecture notes for Algebraic Number Theory by Stevenhagen (http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/ant.pdf). Theorem $3.1$ of these notes handles this problem very quickly.

We need to show that the number ring $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is regular over $2$ and $3$. Following the theorem: $X^4-3\equiv (X-1)^4\bmod 2$, and the remainder of $m(X)$ upon division by $X-1$ is $m(1)=-2\notin 4\mathbb{Z}[X]$, so $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is regular over $2$.

For $3$ we have $X^4-3\equiv X^4 \bmod 3$, for which the remainder of $m(X)$ upon division by $X$ is just $m(0)=-3\notin 9\mathbb{Z}[X]$, so $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is regular over $3$ as well, which proves that $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]=\mathcal{O}_k$.

No heavy lifting procedures involved!

Answer (score 0):

As you've noted we have that $\left | \frac{\mathcal O_K}{\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]} \right |^2 \big | \text{ disc } \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$, so if $\left | \frac{\mathcal O_K}{\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]} \right | \not = 1$, then it's divisible by $2$ or $3$.

Now if we can prove that $f$ is an Eisenstein polynomial for $2$ and $3$ we are done, according to the claim [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/totram.pdf). Now obviously $f$ satisfies the Eisenstein criterion for $3$ and thus by the lemma we have that $3 \nmid \left | \frac{\mathcal O_K}{\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]} \right |$.

On the other side $f(x+1)$ satsifies the Eisenstein criterion for $2$ and so $2 \nmid \left | \frac{\mathcal O_K}{\mathbb{Z}[\alpha-1]} \right |$. However we have $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha-1] = \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ and hence we have that $2 \nmid \left | \frac{\mathcal O_K}{\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]} \right |$. Thus we conclude that $\left | \frac{\mathcal O_K}{\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]} \right | = 1$, i.e. $\mathcal O_K = \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$